# Как обработать url?

Tags: url, ajax

Как правильно будет написать? 
На AJAX

```
url: "/obr/wallProfile.php?a="+a'&b='+b'&c='+c,
```

Вот так должно выглядеть в url

```
/obr/wallProfile.php?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

Comment: На AJAX ничего не пишется, потому что это не язык программирования. Судя по формлению, используется jQuery, и там не нужно ничего вбивать руками, просто использовать ключ data объекта ajax-настроек. В противном случае действительно надо собирать строку самому, но не вот так вот, а с экранирование данных с помощью одной из функций `encodeURI`-семейства.

Comment: @Etki, нет, вы не правы... Я так уже делал, и у меня все работало, только я делал с одной переменной, а тут я 3 сделал.

Comment: @cnofss, Неправ в чем? В том случае, если у вас стандартные ascii-символы (= латиница, скобки, запятые), то разницы никакой не будет, но вот со всяким *юникодом* может начаться веселье. И, конечно, даже с использованием jquery можно из буханки собрать троллейбус, но зачем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
url: "/obr/wallProfile.php?a="+a+"&b="+b+"&c="+c
```

Это если на JS.